# Issue with Visual Studio when developing for Android. The apps opens but only shows the title without controls

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm having issues with Visual Studio 2015. I create a new project for Android, put my stuff (buttons, textviews, etc) and when I try to run the app it deploys and runs OK but I can only see the title in any of my apps. I hace tried several emulators and a real device with the same result.
Any idea??? I've spent the whole day trying to solve this problem.

Comment: You're definitely going to have to give us a lot more information in order for us to be able to help you solve this. For example, are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android? Which emulator are you using? Can you show us the offending code? Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Quote from the flagging dialog: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]"

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply... I'm using Xamarin.Android. My test App is quite easy to recreate, just insert a button in your desing, run your app and it will open but doesn't show the inserted button. Emulators... the Xamarin emulator ask me to setup the network connection with the host and instantly closes. I tried the Visual Studio emulator (Hyper V based) and the result is the same when using my real device, the app opens in the emulator and real device but only shows the title. The problem is not the code as I didn't write any yet.

Comment: Here is what I mean... [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8MLyD2kERHjeHQ1R0Y2QlBNNmc)

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41994318/2316658

Comment: Thanx it works!!! I don't know why I didn't see that line commented.