# Controls showing in designer but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is my first Xamarin app. I have my environment set up in Visual Studio, and have a template project which I can run in the Android emulator.

Having dragged and dropped a couple of controls on to the designer surface, I find that when I run the application in the emulator, neither of the two controls that I have added (a button and a switch) display in the emulator.

I have tried:

- Cleaning the solution
- Rebuilding the solution
- Manually deleting bin and object files
- Unchecking 'Use Fast Deployment' in project Android Options
- Uninstalling from the emulator

But with the same result each time.

[image]

[Project files removed]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of providing a zip with potentially dangerous files, you should include relevant parts of your code here in the StackOverflow post. In this case the source of the AXML file for your layout and the part where you inflate your view would be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just downloaded your code and ran it. Uncommenting `SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);` it worked to me.

```
[Activity(Label = "Tgo.AndroidApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) a nice guide to get you started with Xamarin Android.

Comment: That has worked thanks. Odd that it was commented in the template project, and thanks for the guide recommendation also.

Comment: I should read your answer four days ago, this is were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

navigate to MainActivity.cs and uncomment this code

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
```

and rebuild the solution and debug.

Let me know it if helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to update my Main.xml file with the updates I put into the Main.axml and Rebuild.

Comment: consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer.