# I can not see the graphical interface on the mobile device (Xamarin) and I can not find the generated .apk

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]
I need help, visual studio 2017 with Xamarin recognizes my mobile device and correctly starts the app on my mobile device, but when I insert a Button, a Radiobutton does not show me the graphical interface of the app for more add-ins that inserted the app Goes blank and I do not know what to do, besides that I do not know where it generates the .apk

[image].

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Change Android version (API)
Debug in the Visual Studio emulator
Find some important data on properties
Create a new Black Activity
And none works

Comment: What's the code in your Activity? Btw did you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990579/controls-showing-in-designer-but-not-in-emulator/41991680#41991680

Comment: ¡¡Thank you dude!!